Is there a way to add post processing shader effects in Forge Viewer
I need to create a blur effect for some objects on the scene.
Creating a custom threejs shader material will not help here as the objects don't have any textures.
For threejs there is a "postprocessing" module that allows to create these kinds of effects where you can add and control render passes. Is there a way to make something similar in Forge Viewer?
For this effect I need to render somewhere (but not to screen) then perform blur processing on that buffer and then to render the result to screen.
I'm also using @contecht/react-adsk-forge-viewer React Typescript wrapper for the Forge Viewer.

The APS viewer doesn't provide as much flexibility as three.js when it comes to customizing the post-processing, mainly because there are a lot of performance optimizations built into the rendering pipeline. There's the Autodesk.NPR viewer extension that offers non-photo realistic effects such as cel or pencil drawing, but it doesn't offer blurring.
From your question it's not clear what exactly you're looking for (is it perhaps a depth-of-field effect where objects that are out-of-focus would be blurred?) but if it's something that would be generally useful, you could submit a feature request for the viewer via aps.help@autodesk.com. Alternatively, if the blurring effect is an absolute must, you could consider exporting your 3D data from APS using an open exchange format such as glTF, and load it in a vanilla three.js application with your custom post-processing pipeline.

Thank you for the suggestions. I wanted to add gaussian blur for specific objects only. But maybe some other effects could work, the main idea is to hide the exact geometry from the user but to let them know that this place is already occupied by some equipment.
I have tried to render to an offscreen target from the viewer and then take a texture from it to process it with three.js and then display it on a scene. But it didn't work. Nothing was displayed or errors due to different contexts for viewer and three.js.

I've tried to use viewer.renderer()._render() viewer.renderer().setOffscreenTarget() and overlay scene. Could you please check if something like that would be possible?
